# Internet Explorer and Google Chrome different showup of content

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, layout

I'm setting up an online form where to choose boxes and stuff.
I almost finished the whole thing when I said to my self "Let's try it in IE".

This is the result I want and what comes up in Google Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome result]

And this is what happens in IE:

[image]

And this is the CSS and HTML for that part:

HTML

```
<div id="choosen"><img src="img.jpg" class="center-img" /></div>
```

CSS

```
 img.center-img{
        margin-top:15px;
        position:relative;
        width: <?php echo $width; ?>px;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-<?php echo $width/2; ?>px;
    }
```

Basically the image is centered into the div as this page I'm writing will be included into another one which I never saw and someone else will do it.

**EDITED**

[Here is the link](http://mrweb.info/scatolificio/preventivo.php)

Comment: Having problems with IE is normal and expected. You aren't showing enough for us to help and most of us can't help when there's PHP embedded in it (only show the generated markup). We need a link or a jsfiddle.

Comment: Ok, I edited the post. Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about changing the CSS to

```
img.center-img{
    margin:15px auto 0;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and let u know

Answer (score 0):

Try using css hacks. Here is a link with some on:

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Answer (score 0):

Without a proper doctype, you are in 'quirks mode'. Add this to your very first line with nothing else in front of it: `<!DOCTYPE html>` . That will take you out of quirks and put you into standards mode, especially with regard to Internet Explorer. Then let's see where we stand.

[A doctype is required of all new web pages.](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) The one I show is the newest one and puts all browsers into standards mode where you want to be. Quirks uses a broken box model from the 1990s and you never want to be there.

Comment: That may be, I'll check. Even tho I have to include the file into an "unknown project" which I have no access to

Comment: No, that worsen things up... Sorry. I can make a screenshot and show it to you.

Comment: @NDLombardi - Of course it does. You created the page without a doctype and did it in quirks mode. Thus you used the broken box model. When you used a doctype, the browser switched to the proper box model. miah's "fix" only fixes your problem in this one instance but you will continue to have problems throughout your site forever without a proper doctype. As I said in my answer, a doctype is a requirement for all new web pages.